Cannot install Database-library package in Python2 using pip
I am new to python and moving one test from one (working) to another physical machine (new).
in the process , One of python file has -> from DAL.database import DBC
when I do 'pip2 freeze' on both PCs. The working one had "Database-library==2.0"
But I am unable to install this package using pip.
so I tried install this package on new machine using pip2 but getting ERROR:
root@abc-pc-1:~# pip2 install Database-library
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py:6: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
Collecting Database-library
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 893, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/database-library/

how to install this package or am I missing something else ?

https://pypi.org/project/Database-library/ — error 404. Tрere is no such package as "Database-library". What are you trying to install?

my actual issue is the error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/OneManage/py/NetConf/examples/OAI/call_home_server.py", line 9, in 
from DAL.database import DBC
ImportError: No module named DAL.database
but I am not sure which package to install here ? DAL.database or database?
same code working in other PC , there I see only related packages is below:
Database-library==2.0

(a) Never pip install into the system packages folder. That's a great way to break things. (b) Valid use cases for pip installing as root are very few. You should almost certainly be using a normal unprivileged user. (c) Why are you using pip2 (and therefore Python 2) in 2024?

@user1873657 There is https://pypi.org/project/dal/ but its top-level package is dal, not DAL; and it doesn't have dal.database subpackage. So again we don't know what you're trying to install and cannot help with that unknown package(s).

There was a path X/Y/DAL and it was consisting some php and other files related to some databases. so owner of that repo helped me building and then installing all related package (I am not into php/database) so yes indeed it (DAL) was not an standard packages. But thanks a lot @chris @ phd for helping me out!

BTW: Python 2 is obsolete and there are only very few reasons that would justify its use.
